# Integral Along Y-Axis

Tags: integration

I wish to integrate the following along the Y-axis:$ x = \frac{1}{0.088(log (y)}dy$ from $y= 0$ to $y = 0.42$. I get $y \log y - y$ evaluated between these two limits.  Since $\log y$ can't be $04$, I was wondering if this equation is not capable of being integrated in "closed form" because at $y = 0 $I will have $0 \cdot \log 0$. And $\lim \log y$ as $y$ approaches $0$ is, I think, + infinity. If integral can't be done in closed form, is there another way to do it? Not an expert in math, but wish to learn more. Any help is greatly appreciated. Fred

Answer (score 1):

$ylogy\to 0$ as $y \to 0$  Use L'Hopital's rule on$\frac{logy}{1/y}$ get $\frac{1/y}{-1/y^2}=-y\to 0$.